# C program with a stub program

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, stub

The question is :

> Create a **C** program with a stub program code to calculate taxes?

```
void calculatetaxes (float gross, float deferred, float *fedtax,float *statetax,float *ssitax) ; //3.5 

float calcfedtax(float gross, float deferred); //3.5.1 
float calcstatetax (float fedtax) ; // 3.5.2 
float calcssitax (float gross, float deferred); //3.5.3

// stub program code
#include <stdio.h>
#define ADDR(var) &var

int main (void)
{
    float ft,st,ssit;

    calculatetaxes (1000, 100,ADDR(ft),ADDR(st),ADDR(ssit));

    printf(" fedtax = %8.2f\n",ft);
    printf(" StateTax = %8.2f\n",st); 
    printf(" ssitax = %8.2f\n",ssit);
    fflush(stdin); 
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to make a code to calculate the fedtax,statetax, and ssitax for **C** and was wondering why my void for the stub program doesn't work and the `#define addr(var) $var` doesn't define my variables.

Comment: Don't you mean to use `&` instead of `$` character ?

Comment: wow thank you!! did not see that part.  -fixed it to & now just need to know know why void for my stub program doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by "void" for your stub program?

Comment: when i run the code it says PCH warning: cannot find a suitable header stop location for void. i am new to c program and do not know why it is not working.

Comment: Why do you flush `stdin` here? That's not portable and I don't see a reason why you want to do so…

Comment: It's usually best to start small and simple, then build up. Get one function working before you attempt three. And is there a reason for the `ADDR` macro? Such macros are almost never a good idea.

Comment: @mafso My professor told me use use it.

Comment: @Beta Had to use it to define my variables

Comment: Just about the most pointless and obfuscatory macro ever.

Comment: Is this a course specific to some platform? If it's only about C in general, your professor is just wrong and one of the causes of many bad C questions here and elsewhere. `stdin` and `stdout` are line-buffered and usually terminals are as well; if you don't want line-buffering, use `ncurses` or the like… And your `ADDR` macro is just stupid, don't use it, even if your professor told you so. It's like writing `ADD(a, b)` instead of `a+b` and defining a macro for that.

Comment: @mafso this class is a beginner class which is a formal introduction to the c programming language and well I can only learn what my professor teaches me, so I don't know many ways to do macros and looking up on the internet is harder as they use lots of codes I don't understand.

Comment: Never mind, I didn't intent to blame you; just be sceptical about what  your professor says :) (and I think C is considered difficult mostly because of bad tutorials and teachers, not because of the language itself and I'm sometimes astonished by the mere mass of similar questions here and elsewhere just related to the same misinterpretation of the language, and not understanding buffering is one of the issues; anyway, that's not your actual problem here)

Comment: If your professor wants you to use the macro, use the macro; after you have passed the course and gotten your grade, you can discard these bad practices.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I have seen `#define SPACE ' '`

Answer (score 0):

The lines

```
void calculatetaxes (float gross, float deferred, float *fedtax,float *statetax,float *ssitax) ; //3.5 
float calcfedtax(float gross, float deferred); //3.5.1 
float calcstatetax (float fedtax) ; // 3.5.2 
float calcssitax (float gross, float deferred); //3.5.3
```

are just declarations. They are not implementations. To provide stub implementations, you need to implement them, but not do anything in them.

```
void calculatetaxes (float gross, float deferred, float *fedtax,float *statetax,float *ssitax)
{
   // Implement this function but leave the others that do the main
   // calculations as stub implementations.
   *fedtax = calcfedtax(gross, deferred);
   *statetax = calcstatetax(*fedtax);
   *ssitax = calcssitax(gross, deferred);
}

float calcfedtax(float gross, float deferred)
{
   return 0.0f;
}

float calcstatetax (float fedtax)
{
   return 0.0f;
}

float calcssitax (float gross, float deferred)
{
   return 0.0f;
}
```

Comment: @user3792142: You should also change the `*` in your `printf` statement to `%` (maybe it's just a typo, I'm not sure).

Comment: i changed my stub to your code, and ran it but why do I get negative numbers.

Comment: @user3792142: You use uninitialized values. Anything could happen, even negative numbers.

Comment: @mafso is this a good initialization of the values 
#define FEDTAXRATE 0.15
#define STATETAXRATE 0.07
#define SSITAXRATE 0.0775

Comment: @mafso nevermind changing the values of my floats ft,st, and ssit was the problem here

Comment: @user3792142: The `calculatetaxes()` stub body should perhaps be `{ *fedtax = calcfedtax(gross, deferred); *statetax = calcstatetax(fedtax); *ssitax = calcssitax(gross, deferred); }`.  That way, the returned values are initialized (to `0.0`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, like that suggestion. Updated the answer.